# Permission Error: Problem with search record in salesforce. How to enable process

Tags: search

I have also provided permissions to objects and fields but not able to see those records.

Customize ==> Search ==> Search Settings

(selected object for both checkbox Enhanced Lookups and Lookup Auto-Completion.)

Comment: Did you try the button 'Search All'? You can check the permission for the record by setting it's Id in the URL, e.g.: www.[SFinstance]salesforce.com/recordId

Comment: The object is marked as "enabled for search"?  In past you also needed to have a custom tab to make object searchable but I believe that is no longer the case.